# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.opencv.face.Sample3Native$1

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing an Android based app in OpenCV. When I build the code in Eclipse I don't get any errors, but when I run it it just says "unfortunately FaceRecognition has stopped" and stops. Here is what I get in the Log cat.

```
    06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238): Process: org.opencv.face, PID: 10238
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.opencv.face.Sample3Native$1
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at org.opencv.face.Sample3Native.<init>(Sample3Native.java:73)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1215)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2422)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
06-05 11:05:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(10238):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.opencv.face"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.opencv.face.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
        android:name="org.opencv.face.Sample3Native"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: How did you add **OpenCv** dependency in your project?

Comment: BY ADDING JAR FILE OF OPENCV .

Answer (score 0):

Go to your AndroidManifest.xml in you project
and add your activity class named  ActivityThread.class like this

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityThread"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_thread">
    </activity>
```

Comment: I have added this but the same exception is got by me .

Comment: Use your package name before activity name like this android:name="yourpackage_name.ActivityThread"

Comment: I have done this but the same exception is got by me .

Comment: when do you change it before you ask question? If after my answer, it the log is same?

Comment: After your answer I have changed it . The log is same .

Comment: can you give me snapshot of you AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

In manifest.xml you use android:name="org.opencv.face.Sample3Native". 
From your log it seems that your package name is not correct.
That means Sample3Native class is not in org.opencv.face package 
May be another package. 
Please check it. I hope your problem will solve...

You can simply solve it by creating another activity and move code to the new class. this time
1. Right click on project
2. click new
3 . Click others
4. Android.
5. Android Activity
and create an activity using wizard.
Then move your code to new class

Comment: Sample3Native class is in org.opencv.face package . I have checked this . Also see logcat . It says , "at org.opencv.face.Sample3Native.<init>(Sample3Native.java:73)" . So Sample3Native class is in org.opencv.face package

Comment: is MainActivity and Sample3Native in same package?

Comment: Yes . MainActivity and Sample3Native are in same package

Comment: You can simply solve it by creating another activity and move code to the new class. this time 1. Right click on project 2. click new 3 . Click others 4. Android. 5. Android Activity and create an activity using wizard.

Comment: Same exception is got by me . Now exception goes to new activity .